# target after php call

Tags: php, href, target

In my .php-File, I do the following:

```
<a href="php/make_favorite.php" title="sn" alt=" Favorit " target="_self"><img src="image.jpg"  width="40" height="30" alt="Zgen"></img></a></br>
```

So if somebody clicks on this image, I call a php and the actual recipe will be marked as favourite. 
Now, when I click on it, I get to the `php/make_favorite.php` file.

But what I want to do is, that the user does not see the php-file, he should stay on the same page and see an error or success message.

How do I manage that?

Comment: javascript ajax call or redirect back

Comment: Probably ajax request, otherwise the user would see some delay and further would land on the top of the page :)

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do you have some helpful links for that problem? Never worked with AJAX before..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Ajax (ansynchronous javascript requests):

1) Include e.g. the jQuery javascript library [jQuery](http://jquery.com) in your page like so:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

2) Add the javascript function to request your php/make_favorite.php file

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function addFavourite(data1, data2)
{
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "php/make_favorite.php",
       data: {var1: data1, var2: data2},
       success: function(msg){
           alert( "Favourite remembered!: " + msg ); //Anything you want
       }
    });
}
</script>
```

3) Add the function to the onClick event of your link

```
<a href="#" onClick="addFavourite('image_id', 'some_data')" title="sn" alt=" Favorit " target="_self">...
```

Comment: Thank you, great! So if I need to give the php only the variable recipe_id, I write `var1=recipe_id` ?

Comment: Yes, this is the idea. In the example you will find these values in $_POST (e.g. $_POST['recipe_id']) in your script.

Comment: Hm, I just tried but still get to the `php/make_favorite.php` site. I changed the type in GET, is that a problem? EDIT: Ok, the href was the problem... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To start, your HTML is all over the place, this would be correct syntax:

```
<a href="php/make_favorite.php" title="sn" alt="Favorit" target="_self"><img src="image.jpg"  width="40" height="30" alt="Zgen" /></a><br />
```

Other than that, what you are asking will require either redirecting back to the page somehow in php, e.g.:

```
header("Location: http://www.site.com/page.php");
```

Or you use JavaScript to send an AJAX call to the script so the user stays on the same page when clicking that link.

For AJAX I'd recommend using the [JQuery library](http://jquery.com/), as it makes ajax simple, and there is a lot of documentation to help you out.